# Protect Workbook By Python

Tags: python, excel

I need to set a password to a workbook by python (it requires a password to open the excel file)
Here is the result I need

[image]

Comment: I think this will help: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/protection.html

Comment: @Hadus I tried this as well :(

Comment: I specifically need the Workbook password that prevents opening the document.

Answer (score 0):

I found this at https://www.easyxls.com/manual/tutorials/python/encrypt-excel-file.html:

```
import clr
import gc

clr.AddReference('EasyXLS')
from EasyXLS import *

print("Tutorial 27\n----------\n")

# Create an instance of the class that exports Excel files, having two sheets
workbook = ExcelDocument(2)

# Set the sheet names
workbook.easy_getSheetAt(0).setSheetName("First tab")
workbook.easy_getSheetAt(1).setSheetName("Second tab")

# Set the password for protecting the Excel file when the file is open
workbook.easy_getOptions().setPasswordToOpen("password")

# Export Excel file
print("Writing file C:\\Samples\\Tutorial27.xlsx.")
workbook.easy_WriteXLSXFile("C:\\Samples\\Tutorial27.xlsx")

# Confirm export of Excel file
sError = workbook.easy_getError()

if sError == "":
    print("\nFile successfully created.\n\n")
else:
    print("\nError encountered: " + sError + "\n\n")

# Dispose memory
gc.collect()
```

Comment: thank you for your help, I saw this but it's not free.

Comment: I think you just need `pip install pythonnet`

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testxlsx.py", line 4, in <module>
    clr.AddReference('EasyXLS')
AttributeError: module 'clr' has no attribute 'AddReference'
i got the up error

Comment: That is because you installed the wrong clr package. Do `pip uninstall clr` then `pip install pythonnet`

Comment: i did that and reference to their website i have to install the library for .Net https://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library beside pythonnet

Comment: You can download trial if that is an option. Meanwhile I am looking for another solution.

Comment: Sorry mate I don't think there is an easy way to do this.

Comment: Indeed, you need both pythonnet and easyxls .net trial installed.